# Como ocultar o thead quando todos os tr do tbody estiverem ocultos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table, algoritmo-de-busca

Boa noite, eu estou tentando fazer uma barra de pesquisa que filtre por celulas entre varias tabelas, e gostaria que essa pesquisa **ocultasse** o `<thead>` das tabelas que **não possuam** resultados correspondentes a pesquisa, ou seja, quando o usuário pesquisar Perna, a tabela onde constam Locais e Paises bem como a tabela onde constam Carros e Fabricantes de Motocicletas, **por não ter em nenhuma `<tr>` o texto Perna**, deve ter o `<thead>` ocultado, ou até mesmo toda a `<table>` ocultada.

```js
//pesquisa
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g,
                "");
            $("tbody tr").filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(
                    /[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").indexOf(value) > -1)

            });

            $("thead").each(function () {
                let trVisiveis = $(this).parent().find('tbody tr').not(':hidden');
                trVisiveis.length > 0 ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
            })
        });
    });
// oculta todos menos o DIV selecionado no selector
    $('#select_box').change(function () {
        var select = $(this).find(':selected').text();
        $("div").hide();
        $('#' + select).show();

    }).change();
```

```css
table {
         font-family: arial, sans-serif;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         width: 100%;
         }
         td, th {
         border: 1px solid #dddddd;
         text-align: left;
         padding: 8px;
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchInput" placeholder="Digite para filtrar...">
<br />
<br/>
<select id="select_box">
<option>tabelas-1</option>
<option>tabelas-2</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<div id="tabelas-1">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Corpo</th>
    <th>Cores</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Cabeca</td>
    <td>Azul</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Braco</td>
    <td>Vermelho</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Perna</td>
    <td>Amarelo</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Carros</th>
    <th>Fabricantes de Motocicletas</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Porshe</td>
    <td>Harley</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mustang</td>
    <td>Yamaha</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Camaro</td>
    <td>Honda</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Locais</th>
    <th>Paises</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Aqui</td>
    <td>Quenia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ali</td>
    <td>Alemanha</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Acola</td>
    <td>India</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="tabelas-2">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Display</th>
          <th>Datas comemorativas</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Amoled</td>
          <td>Natal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>LCD</td>
          <td>Páscoa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>OLED</td>
          <td>Ação de graças</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Linhas de celulares</th>
          <th>Sistemas Operacionais</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Redmi</td>
          <td>Ubuntu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Galaxy S</td>
          <td>Mint</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>iPhone</td>
          <td>Fedora</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como alcançar isso? Obrigado.

PS: Algumas tentativas, **sem sucesso**, a partir do [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877353/hide-parent-thead-if-all-tr-in-tbody-are-hidden-displaynone)

Sugestão do [SeeTheC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940020/seethec)

```
function hide() {

$('tbody').each(function(){  
  if($(this).not("tr:hidden").length=1)
    {      
      $(this).parent().find("thead").hide();
    }
});
  
  
}
```

Sugestão do [Musa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353011/musa)

```
$('tbody').each(function(){
    if ($(this).has("> tr:visible").length === 0){
        $(this).closest('table').hide();
    }
});
```

Sugestão do [acontell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3565885/acontell)

```
$("#filter").change(function () {// Select changes and filters rows of the different tables.
    var class_to_filter = "." + $(this).val();// I'm accessing rows by class in order to close them, you may access them using some other method.

    $.each($(class_to_filter), function (i, item) {// For each one of them, close and check if you have to close thead as well.
        var $tr = $(item).closest('tr'),
            $tbody = $tr.closest('tbody'),
            $thead = $tbody.siblings('thead'),
            numOfVisibleRows;

        $tr.hide();// Hide row.
        numOfVisibleRows = $('tr:visible', $tbody).length;// Number of sibling rows visible.

        if (!numOfVisibleRows) {// if 0, hide thead.
            $thead.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode alterar seu script assim:

O método **parents()** é utilizado para selecionar o elemento pai **table** para ocultar, e o elemento **tbody** para verificar se tem o conteúdo pesquisado.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("tbody tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
          // Utilizando parents e selecionando tbody para verificar se tem o texto do input
           $(this).parents("table").toggle($(this).parents("tbody").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

        });

      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte:

Após rodar seu script para esconder colunas que não entram no seu filtro, rode outro script que irá computar se há alguma coluna visível para aquela `thead`.

Como fazer isso?

Busque por todos os elementos que são `thead` em sua página:

```
$("thead")
```

Em seguida, rode um script para cada um deles através da função `each`:

```
$("thead").each(function (){});
```

Dentro da função que irá rodar para cada `thead`, para alcançar suas linhas do `tbody`, você precisa pegar o `tbody` do contexto e usar a função `parent`:

```
$(this).parent()
```

Dessa forma, acabamos obtendo a `table` relacionada à aquela `thead`. Agora vamos procurar pelas linhas do `tbody`, da seguinte maneira:

```
$(this).parent().find('tbody tr')
```

Faça um filtro que irá excluir as linhas que estão escondidas através da função `not`:

```
$(this).parent().find('tbody tr').not(':hidden')
```

Depois disso tudo, é só ver quantos elementos essa consulta retornou... e aplicar sua lógica para mostrar ou não a `thead`.

Um exemplo dessa implementação, ficaria assim:

```
$("thead").each(function (){ 
    let trVisiveis = $(this).parent().find('tbody tr').not(':hidden');
    trVisiveis.length > 0 ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide(); 
})
```

E o seu script ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("tbody tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

    });
    
    $("thead").each(function (){ 
        let trVisiveis = $(this).parent().find('tbody tr').not(':hidden');
        trVisiveis.length > 0 ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide(); 
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Boa noite, @Bruno Warmling, eu atualizei o código da postagem para incluir um `<selector>`, e durante a pesquisa, quando eu digito "ca", por exemplo, ele filtra as linhas contendo "Cabeca" e "Camaro", mas quando eu alterno o `<selector>`, para tabelas-2, ele acha a linha contendo "Ação de graças", mas não mostra o `<thead>`, e se dentro de 'tabelas-2', eu limpo a barra de pesquisa, e volto para 'tabelas-1' ele não mostra nenhum `<thead>`. Você teria alguma ideia de como contornar essa situação?

Comment: cara, ficar alterando sua pergunta não ajuda em nada... minha boa vontade de responder se acaba por aqui.

Comment: Sinto muito, e obrigado.

Answer (score -3):

Parabéns, muito bom!! usei no meu código assim:

abrirQGRobo = function(registro) {
        $("#qgroboModal").modal();
         $(".class-robo").each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
         })
         $(".tr_" + registro).each(function () {
            $(this).show();
         })
    }